# Java + Spring - Put a message on @DecimalMin constraint

Tags: java, spring, constraints, bigdecimal

Simple enough: How do you put a `message` on a `@DecimalMin` constraint? I know you can use `message` with the `@Size` constraint, but how would you do it with `@DecimalMin`? I'm using `@DecimalMin` on a BigDecimal, as my variable was a decimal and docs said that the constraints were more flexible with BigDecimal than anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `message` in the same way as you would do witl a `@Size` constraint:

```
@DecimalMin(value = "0", message = "Hello, validated world!")
private Double number;
```

Comment: You saved my day. Have fun with your 10k!

Comment: The reason it wasn't working is because I didn't know you could put the `value` attribute. My code was like this:

`@DecimalMin("1000.0")`

and `@DecimalMin("1000.0", message="")` wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that ;-)